# Sum data from muliple cells, multiply by other cell range, reference on other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ive had a couple issues with this workbook recently this seems like the biggest.  As you can see in the pics, this a time sheet that needs F15 multiplied by Q15, then added to F20 which was multiplied by Q20, etc etc.  Basically looking for hours multiplied by specific rates added to other hours multiplied by their specific rates for the same day.  The formula I found that that was used on the other sheet to reference this was:

> =SUM(Bill!F15*Bill!$Q$15+(Bill!F16*Bill!$Q$16+(Bill!F17*Bill!$Q$17+(Bill!F18*Bill!$Q$18))))+SUM(Bill!F20*Bill!$Q$20+(Bill!F21*Bill!$Q$21+(Bill!F22*Bill!$Q$22+(Bill!F23*Bill!$Q$23))))

Pretty long but it worked.  No as you can see there is 13 rows in between the first week and second week (when referencing Reg1 on 1/7 vs Reg1 on 1/15), but then between the next set there is 18 in between.  It all needs to basically do what the formula up top does, but then input on the second sheet and skip a row each time.  Im stumped.  Any help would be ridiculously appreciated.

[image: !Bill sheet]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj5sB.jpg)[[image: Sheet 2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZJ52.jpg)

Comment: This will require some work with the OFFSET function and IF statements to jump over blank or unwanted rows.

Comment: Try something like this: `=SUM(IF(Bill!F15:F23<>"",Bill!F15:F23*Bill!Q15:Q23,0))` I can't see your screenshots, so I'm assuming that column F is empty in the rows you don't want to include. If that's not true, you should be able to modify the if statement to fit your needs. It's an array formula, so you have to confirm entry with ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: F is one of the column that, when full, will specifically be the column that gets multiplied by column Q.  So Bill!F15 needs to only multiply by Bill!Q15, Bill!F15 only by Bill!Q16, F17 by Q17 and F18 by Q18.  Then the all get added together.  Then it skips to F20 by Q20 up to F23 by Q23, then those get added together.  That whole thing there will just be one day, then it needs to go to G15 by Q15, and follow the same previous pattern.  At then end of that, thats only 1 week and it needs to output to cells that skip to every other cell.  Unfortunate you cant see the pics it would make sense

Comment: @Kyle, Ok so that does totally work, but I need when I skip 2 rows by copying the formula on my output sheet, it needs to skip from the block of F15:F18 down to F20:F23.  Then skip a row on the output sheet and move to F46:F49.  So every time I skip 1 row on the output sheet, it should do that formula you wrote but then skip down 1, then skip down 4, then skip 1, then skip 9, then skip 1, then skip 4, then skip 1, then skip 20, then it repeats.  Skip 1, 4, 1, 9, 1, 4, 1, 20, 1, 4, 1, 9, 1 ,4, 1 ,20, etc etc.  All while i copy the formula down 2 rows on the out sheet

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to define some type of criteria that you can use to include rows. Like adding a column for the name or SSN of the employee on your data sheet.

Comment: Whats my best way to do that?  Im pretty knowledgeable when it comes to excel but this is a realm that this above me at this point.  Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave it an honest effort but the way your data is organized makes it too hard to work with. I think you need to reorganize your data so it all fits in one table. Then you can just make a Pivot Table.